# Text overlapping in <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was insert text to `<div>` from java script. Looks like `<div>` tag width and height already setup. So If I insert large paragraph text then `<div>`  is overlapping on to other `<div>` under below.

```
    $("#formDescription").text($("#Description").val());
```

### html

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1" id="box_front_bottom" style="display: none;">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-body">
            ---
            ---
             <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-5" style="overflow: auto">
                    @Html.Label("Description", new { @class = "control-label" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7" id="formDescription">
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image]

If I use less text, it will show like this

[image]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ItsMeSri/Q2FHr/1/)

Comment: and the css is....???

Comment: could you add a little more information?

Comment: can you add fiddle..?

Comment: css is the bootstrap.

Comment: Then make a http://jsfiddle.net with that code we can't reproduce the problem

Comment: @Danko  Here is the JSFiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/ItsMeSri/Q2FHr/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the bootstrap CSS you are setting the containers of that information with `float:left` you may need to clear the floats to keep each form in separate lines; use this:

```
.form-group:after {
  content: " ";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/Q2FHr/2/

Answer (score 0):

use `display: inline-block;` and `max-height`

Comment: this is not working. How to expand div after inserting big content inside?